# declaring variables with a constant in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Sorry guys, didn't know how to word this one.
Still learning jquery and have searched for the answer but haven't found anything.

When declaring this variable I would like to add these two parts together but I don't know how.

```
  var link = $'page.html' + (this).attr('rel');
```

That is my attempt but obviously it doesn't work.

I'm trying to make the variable read "page.html rel > *"
So it will always be referencing the page but then I can store different div id's in the rel and pass them to .load()

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: `var link = 'page.html' + $(this).attr('rel') + ' > *';`
Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're quite close:

```
var link = 'page.html ' + $(this).attr('rel') + ' > *';
```

That will wrap a jQuery instance around `this` (I'm guessing this is in an event handler function?), retrieve the `rel` attribute from that element, and put `'page.html '` in front of it and `' > *'` after it. So if `rel` is `"#foo"`, you'd end up with `page.html #foo > *`.

If the `rel` won't have the `#`, be sure to add it, e.g.:

```
var link = 'page.html #' + $(this).attr('rel') + ' > *';
```

I'm not sure you really want the `' > *'` part, though, if you're going to use this with `load`.

Comment: I think he wants to have it as a "template" variable, so if he changes the `rel` the variable value will change

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly what I was after. Thank you!
So you can literally just add things together with + and plain text just needs to be incased in '' 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bennjamin_: Glad that helped. Yes, in JavaScript, if the value on either side of a `+` is a string, the `+` means "concatenate" (e.g., join strings together). Otherwise, `+` is numeric addition. Separately: JavaScript strings can be enclosed in either single or double quotes. Within single quotes, you can use double quotes without escaping them; within double quotes, you can use single quotes without escaping them. Otherwise there's no difference. So `"test ' test"` `===` `'test \' test'`, and `'test " test'` `===` `"test \" test"`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want to do?

```
$('#your_link').click(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $('#content').load($this.attr('url') + ' ' + $this.attr('rel') + ' > *');
  return false;
});
```